# iOS Shoutcast access metadata using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, shoutcast

Ok so I've looked at many similar stack questions but none of them worked or were too old to even be considered.

Here is the stream adres if that's important: http://51.255.8.139:8822/stream

NOTE: I'm new to iOS programming and this is my first project.

I used `AVFoundation`. `AVAsset` to enclose `URL` and `AVPlayer` to play it. That works.

I can't however get any metadata from the stream. Like current song name.

---

Notable things I tried:

- `asset.timedMetadata` nothing there
- [official apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/finding_metadata_values) `availableMetadataFormats` was empty
- ```
   playerItem!.observe(\AVPlayerItem.timedMetadata, options: .new) {
           (player, change) in print(change)
      }
  ```

  also empty

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to do the same,
I got the answer on apple developer forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650170

But basically `timedMetadata` should work, (prior to iOS 14 it will only give stream name).